# porting VS to linux: no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gcc

i'm trying to port code that compiles ok with visual studio and on linux gcc4.6 throws this:

```
PieMenu.cpp: In member function ‘void PieMenu::AddButtons()’:
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(const wchar_t*)’

PieMenu.cpp:110:44: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:531:7: note: void std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:531:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const wchar_t*’ to ‘const char*’
```

this is the relevant part of .cpp:

```
void PieMenu::AddButtons()
{
        CString slash = CUtils::Slash();

        CString texturePath,namelistPath=m_pluginPath;
#ifndef linux
        texturePath =  L".." + slash + L".." + slash; // On windows plugin is located two levels below...
        namelistPath += texturePath;
#endif
        texturePath += L"data" +slash+ m_folderpath + slash + L"textures" + slash;
        namelistPath += L"data" +slash+ m_folderpath + slash + m_folderpath + L".txt";


        for(int i=0;i<m_buttonCount;i++)
        {
            CString bPath = texturePath + m_folderpath + CString(i);
            m_buttons.push_back(ToolButton());
            m_buttons[i].Setup( bPath.GetWideString(), i);
        }

        string l_str;
        ifstream infile;
```

this is the line 110 of the code:

```
        infile.open (namelistPath.GetWideString());

        int k=0;
        while(!infile.eof() && k < m_buttonCount) // To get you all the lines.
        {
            std::getline(infile,l_str); // Saves the line in STRING.
            m_buttons[k].SetName(CString(l_str.data()));
            k++;
        }
        infile.close();
}
```

all hints and help appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++ standard library doesn't define an `open()` function for file streams taking the file name as wide characters, independent on whether the stream is for wide characters or not. That is, if you have a wide character string you want to use as a file name you need to convert it to a suitable sequence of `char`s. How to do this in the desired way depends on your needs.

From the looks of it, Windows implements a method to open files using wide character strings and their standard C++ library supports an extension allowing you to call `open()` (or the constructor of a file stream which just calls `open()`) using a wide character string.